# Can I add LUKS/LVM to an already installed Ubuntu system?

Tags: 12.04, lvm, luks

I know how to install a LUKS/LVM  Ubuntu system using the alternative CD. Is it possible to do this with an already installed normal system? Meaning that I have an unecrypted system now and don't want to do a reinstall for LUKS/LVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to re-install as a part of encryption (LUKS) writes random data to the hard drive over writing your data. You will have to back up your data an re-install.

Answer (score 0):

No, your best option would be to use [encryptfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome).